# Excel VBA IFERROR Formula not working

Tags: excel, indexing, match, vba

I'm having an issue inputting a forumla into a cell in my VBA.  I'm just trying to put a simple Index & Match formula into Cell "V2", the code works perfectly fine until I add an IFERROR clause at the begining.  I'm not sure what the problem is because I have the same formula code working above for a different cell.  Here's my code

```
wsO.Range("V2").FormulaArray = _
    "=IFERROR(INDEX('[Blue.xls]2015'!$D$24:$D$209,MATCH(I3&L3,'[Blue.xls]2015'!$A$24:$A$209&'[Blue.xls]2015'!$B$24:$B$209,0)),"""")"
```

Any thoughts are much appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: "not working" isn't very informative. What do you expect to happen and what does your formula actually do?

Comment: The [IFERROR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5) was introduced with XL2007 but you are using it on an XLS (compatibility mode...?).

Comment: @Jeeped That probably isn't an issue since OP says the same formula is working as expected for a different cell.

Comment: Jeeped - I don't see it being a compatability issue because I've already used this forumla perviously in my code and it worked like a charm.  That is why I am so perplexed by this error.

Comment: The Error I am getting is Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error.  The purpose of this line is to search another document for matching data and return it's value in column D, and if there's an error I want it to just input nothing instead of an #N/A

Comment: The code works for me in a new workbook or an XLS (in compatibility mode) against an open Blue.xls XL2003 but I have the compatibility pack installed.

Comment: Your code works for me

Comment: I just tried it in a new worksheet, and I'm still getting the error.  Correct me if I'm wrong but the premise of this code is to just input the value into the cell, It doesn't actually loop through the other workbook (the formula itself does that not the code).  So it shouldn't matter what is in the quotes because regardless of anything the code just puts it inside the cell.

Comment: That's not quite correct. You cannot put an invalid formula into a cell. Try putting a [Range.PrefixCharacter property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.prefixcharacter.aspx) in front of the `=` like `"'=IFERROR(INDEX(...` and then go to the worksheet and remove the `'` finishing off with CSE. btw, what version of Excel and VBE is actually running the code?

Comment: The version is 2010, I'll give the prefixcharacter a shot if not I'm at a loss, my previous usage of the code has been utilizing xls workbooks as well so I have no idea where the issue resides.